# How to add RTE (Rich Text Edit) for the text area in TYPO3 backend module extension template

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a TYPO3 backend module extension. I want to replace the text area with RTE in the template.

Comment: In which TYPO3 version are you talking about? RTE has been removed in newer version.

Comment: Typo 3 version: 9.5.11

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can configure this with CKeditor plugin. You can follow the step below to make this happen,

1) You can add the JQuery plugin from TYPO3 core here:
sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/ckeditor.js

2) Load the plugin in the backend module, you can use the below link as a reference.
See: [Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Be/Container.html#examples)

3) Add custom JS file to write your custom JQuery script (Just like step 2)

4) In your custom JS, initialize CKEditor.

```
$( 'textarea.editor' ).ckeditor(); // this is your HTML field
```

See: [Reference](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_jquery.html)

Also, you can look at the [official document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/index.html) for configuring this.

Hope this will help you!